# Make ansible ignore variable in template when checking changed state

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I need to create a template file that includes a random string.

I only need to set this random value once, but it would be nice to re-use the role file to update the output file if static parts of the template get updated.

The way I have it running now, every time the playbook is run, a new random string is generated, and therefore the template is changed -> a new file is uploaded and the random string is replaced in the destination file.

How can I make ansible disregard this variable when checking if the template changed?

Comment: What about a checksum when created and check with the stat module? Save the checksum to a file and check if it changed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *how* random the string needs to be, you can generate a password in such a way that it's always the same for any given host and simply use it in the template.

The [Ansible Jinja2 filter docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) suggest "an idempotent method to generate unique hashes per system is to use a salt that is consistent between runs":

```
{{ 'secretpassword' | password_hash('sha512', 65534 | random(seed=inventory_hostname) | string) }}
```

Note that to decrease how guessable the resulting value is, you'll need to be sure to use something that's unique per host for the seed (e.g. `inventory_hostname` might always be `localhost` if your playbook is running locally):

```
PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************

TASK [Debug inventory_hostname.] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  inventory_hostname: localhost

TASK [Debug idempotent random string.] ***********************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: $6$rounds=656000$21889$o7dtKP5aAPzYxyDIn9wbTRJMoQboNXtp0snNtTDvcU030aKvMyxsLzTGUuunG/hW2lBSLh/MS/C/c6Dx/uXo51
```